# Как сделать такой круг на svg со сменой цвета?

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, svg

Есть такой круг

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать его на SVG, чтобы можно было заполнять его бордер  и менять цвет на каждую оценку.
Например:  для оценки 2 была бы заполненность бордера лишь на 20%, и т.п

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/poJPdRR так сказать похоже

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если при оценке **`2`** нужно заполнить круг на `20%`, значит будет пяти бальная система и при оценке `5` круг должен быть заполнен полностью - `100%`

Чтобы легче было реализовать шаги между оценками - `20%`, я выбрал радиус окружности равный `r="79.61"` при котором длина окружности будете равна  `2 * 79.61 * 3.14 = 500`

Соответственно диапазон одной оценки будет равен `100px`

Выбираю шаг `step = 100` для одной оценки

```js
let Circ_points = document.querySelector("#Circ_points");
let points = document.querySelector("#points"); 
let txt = document.querySelector("#txt1");
points.onchange = function(){

Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", "500" - points.value);
  
 if (points.value < 100 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
 }

 if (points.value == 100 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "gold");
  }
  if (points.value == 200 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "dodgerblue");
  }
  if (points.value == 300 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "#5FB62F");
  }
 if (points.value == 400 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "purple");
  }
 
  if (points.value == 500 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "crimson");
  }
  txt.innerHTML = (points.value/100);
    
  }
```

```css
.container {
width:35vw;
height:35vh;
}
.track{
fill:none;
stroke:#CACACA;
stroke-width:15; 
}
input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 120px;
  width: 80px;
  background:#DCF1F6;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

svg{
  display: block;
  background:#F3F3F3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" >
  <circle class="track"  cx="150" cy="150" r="79.61" />
  <circle id="Circ_points" transform="rotate(-90 150 150)"  cx="150" cy="150" r="79.61" 
           fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="500" 
    stroke-dashoffset="500"  />
  <text x="50%" y="50%" id="txt1"  text-anchor="middle" font-size="42px">0</text>
   <text x="150" y="180"   text-anchor="middle" font-size="24px" fill="#8E8E8E">
     <tspan>Суммарная</tspan> 
     <tspan x="150" y="200">оценка</tspan>  </text>
</svg>

<input type="number"  id="points"  step="100" value="0" min="0" max="500">
</div>
```

Если необходимо, чтобы в оценке были знаки после запятой, то необходимо сделать шаг более мелкий. Например `25px`

```js
let Circ_points = document.querySelector("#Circ_points");
let points = document.querySelector("#points"); 
let txt = document.querySelector("#txt1");
points.onchange = function(){

Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", "500" - points.value);
  
 if (points.value < 100 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
 }

 if (points.value == 100 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "gold");
  }
  if (points.value == 200 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "dodgerblue");
  }
  if (points.value == 300 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "#5FB62F");
  }
 if (points.value == 400 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "purple");
  }
 
  if (points.value == 500 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "crimson");
  }
  txt.innerHTML = (points.value/100);
    
  }
```

```css
.container {
width:35vw;
height:35vh;
}
.track{
fill:none;
stroke:#CACACA;
stroke-width:15; 
}
input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 120px;
  width: 80px;
  background:#DCF1F6;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

svg{
  display: block;
  background:#F3F3F3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" >
  <circle class="track"  cx="150" cy="150" r="79.61" />
  <circle id="Circ_points" transform="rotate(-90 150 150)"  cx="150" cy="150" r="79.61" 
           fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="500" 
    stroke-dashoffset="500"  />
  <text x="50%" y="50%" id="txt1"  text-anchor="middle" font-size="42px">0</text>
   <text x="150" y="180"   text-anchor="middle" font-size="24px" fill="#8E8E8E">
     <tspan>Суммарная</tspan> 
     <tspan x="150" y="200">оценка</tspan>  </text>
</svg>


<input type="number"  id="points"  step="25" value="0" min="0" max="500">
</div>
```

**Вариант с цветной цифрой оценки**

```js
let Circ_points = document.querySelector("#Circ_points");
let points = document.querySelector("#points"); 
let txt = document.querySelector("#txt1");
points.onchange = function(){

Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", "500" - points.value);
  
 if (points.value < 100 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "black"); 
    txt.setAttribute("fill", "black");
 }

 if (points.value == 100 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "#A97D4B");
    txt.setAttribute("fill", "#A97D4B");
  }
  if (points.value == 200 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "dodgerblue");
   txt.setAttribute("fill", "dodgerblue");
  
  }
  if (points.value == 300 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "#5FB62F");
  txt.setAttribute("fill", "#5FB62F");
  }
 if (points.value == 400 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "purple");
  txt.setAttribute("fill", "purple");
  }
 
  if (points.value == 500 ) {
  Circ_points.setAttribute("stroke", "crimson");
  txt.setAttribute("fill", "crimson");
  
  }
  txt.innerHTML = (points.value/100);
    
  }
```

```css
.container {
width:35vw;
height:35vh;
}
.track{
fill:none;
stroke:#CACACA;
stroke-width:15; 
}
input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 120px;
  width: 80px;
  background:#DCF1F6;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

svg{
  display: block;
  background:#F3F3F3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" >
  <circle class="track"  cx="150" cy="150" r="79.61" />
  <circle id="Circ_points" transform="rotate(-90 150 150)"  cx="150" cy="150" r="79.61" 
           fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="500" 
    stroke-dashoffset="500"  />
  <text x="50%" y="50%" id="txt1"  text-anchor="middle" font-size="42px">0</text>
   <text x="150" y="180"   text-anchor="middle" font-size="24px" fill="#8E8E8E">
     <tspan>Суммарная</tspan> 
     <tspan x="150" y="200">оценка</tspan>  </text>
</svg>


<input type="number"  id="points"  step="25" value="0" min="0" max="500">
</div>
```

Comment: Он этот вопрос на toster задавал, и ему там же дали ответ на плагине каком то...я по этому не стал писать ответ здесь

Comment: @MaximLensky кинь ссылку посмотрю

Comment: тачка нормально получилась ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/QWbgpjg я делал вот по этому вопросу : https://otvet.mail.ru/question/218777325